# Dailymotion js api cannot play de video into the apiready event

Tags: dailymotion-api

just trying to play a video after apiready event.
My code:

```
var player = DM.player("dm-player", {video: someValidId });
player.addEventListener("apiready", function(e)
{
    e.target.play();
});
```

The video player only load, but not start to reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The autoplay needs to be set in the params object

`player = DM.player("player", {
        video: videoId,
        width: "800",
        height: "450",
        params: { autoplay: 1, }
    });`